# How can you use Private links for Synapse workspace SQL On-Demand?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-private-link

My workspace has the managed vnet enabled. I have managed to configure a private link to the default ADLS Gen 2 following the guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-create-managed-private-endpoints

The private link connection works in a copy activity (pipeline in the workspace). However, accessing the storage account from the serverless pool does not seem to work. Is there any guide on this yet? Are there any requirements regarding the usage of AAD pass-through, SAS tokens or managed identities? Is it supported at all currently?

Error: File "" cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process.

This error results from both AD passthrough and data source with managed identity scenarios. I can get the connection to work through the managed identity by using the checkbox "Access to trusted Microsoft services" (in ADLS), so they should be configured correctly. However, when blocking the access to the ADLS the connection stops working.

EDIT: According to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-storage-access-control?tabs=user-identity
, access to a firewall protected storage account only woks with a managed identity and "Allow trusted Microsoft.." setting turned on. Does this also apply to private links, meaning that the only way to access a storage account behind a firewall is through allowing access to Microsoft services and private links cannot be utilized for the serverless pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it applies to private links too.

<strike>As you seen in that [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-storage-access-control?tabs=user-identity#supported-storages-and-authorization-types), currently you can run queries over firewall protected storage account by using Managed Identity only.</strike>

In the upcoming period you would have an option to run those queries by using User Identity (AAD pass-through) which is more convenient.

### Update 1

Now you can configure an exception for Azure Synapse workspace in your Storage account firewall settings. For full explanation see [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-storage-access-control?tabs=user-identity#configuration-via-powershell)

Short summary:

**1. Open PowerShell or install PowerShell**

**2. Install the updated Az. Storage Module:**

```
Install-Module -Name Az.Storage -RequiredVersion 3.0.1-preview -AllowPrerelease
```

**Make sure that you use version 3.0.1 or newer.** You can check your Az.Storage version by running this command:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name  Az.Storage | select Version
```

**3. Connect to your Azure Tenant:**

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

**4. Define variables in PowerShell:**

- Resource group name - you can find this in Azure portal in overview of Synapse workspace.
- Account Name - name of storage account that is protected by firewall rules.
- Tenant ID - you can find this in Azure portal in Azure Active Directory in tenant information.
- Resource ID - you can find this in Azure portal in overview of Synapse workspace.

```
$resourceGroupName = "<resource group name>"
$accountName = "<storage account name>"
$tenantId = "<tenant id>"
$resourceId = "<Synapse workspace resource id>"
```

**Make sure that resource id matches this template.**

It's important to write **resourcegroups** in lower case. Example of one resource id:

```
/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourcegroups/{resource-group}/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/{name-of-workspace}
```

**5. Add Storage Network rule:**

```
Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $accountName -TenantId $tenantId -ResourceId $resourceId
```

**6. Verify that rule was applied in your storage account:**

```
$rule = Get-AzStorageAccountNetworkRuleSet -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $accountName
$rule.ResourceAccessRules
```

---

*In the upcoming period there will be an option to configure storage account firewall from Azure portal UI.*

---

### Update 2

Configuration via Azure portal UI is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-storage-access-control?branch=pr-en-us-153402&tabs=user-identity#configuration-via-azure-portal)!

1. Search for your Storage Account in Azure portal.
2. Go to Networking under section Settings.
3. In Section "Resource instances" add an exception for your Synapse workspace.
4. Select Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces as a Resource type.
5. Select name of your workspace as an Instance name.
6. Click Save.