# Running query using serverless sql pool (built-in) on CSV file in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 failed

Tags: azure, csv, azure-synapse

I uploaded my CSV file into my Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using [Azure Synapse portal](https://web.azuresynapse.net). Then I tried `select Top 100 rows` and got an error after running auto-generated SQL.
**Auto-generated SQL:**

```
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://accountname.dfs.core.windows.net/filesystemname/test_file/contract.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION='2.0'
    ) AS [result]
```

**Error:**

```
File 'https://accountname.dfs.core.windows.net/filesystemname/test_file/contract.csv'
cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error in Synapse Studio has [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand#query-fails-because-file-cannot-be-opened) (which leads to self-help document) underneath it which explains the error itself.

Do you have rights needed on the storage account?

You must have **Storage Blob Data Contributor** or **Storage Blob Data Reader** in order for this query to work.

Summary from the docs:

> You need to have a Storage Blob Data Owner/Contributor/Reader role to
> use your identity to access the data. Even if you are an Owner of a
> Storage Account, you still need to add yourself into one of the
> Storage Blob Data roles.

Check out the full documentation for [Control Storage account access for serverless SQL pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-storage-access-control?tabs=user-identity#supported-storage-authorization-types)

---

**If your storage account is protected with firewall rules** then take a look at this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65013478/14368791).

Reference [full docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-storage-access-control?tabs=user-identity#configuration-via-powershell).

Answer (score 0):

I just took your code & updated the path to what I have and it worked just worked fine

```
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://XXX.dfs.core.windows.net/himanshu/NYCTaxi/PassengerCountStats.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION='2.0'
    ) AS [result]
```

Please check if the path to which you have uploaded the file and the one used in the script is the same .
You can do this to check that
Navigate to WS -> Data -> ADLS gen2 -> Go to the file -> right click go to the property and copy the Uri from there paste in the script .

Comment: It works with public data like NYCTaxi dataset. Not working with private data in our linked Data Lake.